# jQuery is not defined

Tags: 7, javascript

I just started my project which I haven't touched in a while. I got the most recent develop version of it using git and I up'ed my docker. Once I opened my website I saw, that something is off. Console is saying that "Drupal is not defined" and if I visit pages-> --any page-- -> content, the layout is off. 
[image]

In the console here it says ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

What I already tried to do:

- Rebuild my project
- Resave configuration of jQuery update
- Clearing cache (lol)
- Checking if JS is enabled on my browser

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: give this a shot : https://www.drupal.org/node/111596

Comment: @MassoudiMalek Thank you, but I tried this solution before posting here, sadly nothing helped. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who might experience this, for me Minify module was causing this, I think I lacked some configuration to use minified JS, so my localhost couldn't load JS, after disabling Minify module, everything was fine. Not the best solution, but for fast results its okay.

P.S. DON'T FORGET TO ENABLE IT IF YOU TWEAK SOME JS CODE AND EXPORT IT AS FEATURE.